# HTMLUnit with FIddler and SSL

Tags: java, automated-tests, fiddler, htmlunit

I configured HTMLUnit so it uses Fiddler as a proxy. But when Fiddler is capturing traffic and I browse a site which has ssl(https) I get the following error in Java

"javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated"

Is there anyway fix around this? I want to see all SSL traffic in Fiddler.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure Java to trust Fiddler's root certificate, which you can export from Fiddler using the Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS > Export Root Certificate button.