# How to use SoapUI and Fiddler together for SOAP services over https

Tags: java, certificate, soapui, fiddler

Like many folks I am trying to use Fiddler to see the actual request/response on issuing web service calls using SOAP UI.

1. I can issue the service call with SOAP UI, and see the request and response XML.
2. I fire up Fiddler, and I can still issue the service call with SOAP UI, and see the request and response XML, but there is not trace of the request or response in Fiddler.
3. As per several suggestions on this site (example [SoapUI with Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744602/soapui-with-fiddler)) I go to File->Preferences->Proxy on Soap UI, and set the proxy server to 127.0.0.1 with port 8888.
4. If Fiddler is not open, I will now get the following error in SOAP UI, which is expected: "Error getting response; org.apage.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http:// 127.0.0.1:8888 refused"
5. If Fiddler is open, and I am attempting to see the request/response in Fiddler to a non-SSL site, then all works fine.
6. If Fiddler is open, and I am attempting to see the request/response in Fiddler to a SSL site using https, I get the following error: "Error getting response; javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated"
7. Based on the following (and other) advice in SO [HTMLUnit with FIddler and SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057440/htmlunit-with-fiddler-and-ssl), I have exported the Fiddler root certificate, and imported from the Java Console into the "Secure Sites CA" list.  (Even if I run the Java Console as administrator, I can only import as "User" not "System".... not sure if that is relevant).
8. It appears to have no effect whatsover that I imported this certificate to the Java console.  I am still geteting the same message as in #6.

I sure would appreciate any help that could get me seeing the SOAP UI HTTPS SSL requests and responses in Fiddler.

Comment: Stated another way, points #6 and #7 are the only relevant ones, making the question: `How can I get SoapUI to trust Fiddler's root certificate?`